# Silverlight Prism fails to resolve modules on load but not always

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism

I'm using prism 4.1 with mef to develop front-office application and i've got problems with it. Sometimes during modules loading process the application fails with exception

> Could not load file or assembly "Sl.Common.Model, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken = null" or one of its dependencies. Can not find the file specified.

Modules have dependencies (AuditModule and LoadersModule depends on CommonModule).

```
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                          xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
                          xmlns:Modularity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism">

<!-- language: lang-xml -->    
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo  Ref="Sl.Common.Model.xap" InitializationMode="WhenAvailable" ModuleName="CommonModule"/>
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo Ref="Sl.Loaders.xap" ModuleName="LoadersModule">
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
            <sys:String>CommonModule</sys:String>
        </Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
    </Modularity:ModuleInfo>
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo Ref="Sl.Audit.xap" ModuleName="AuditModule">
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
            <sys:String>CommonModule</sys:String>
        </Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
    </Modularity:ModuleInfo>

</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

The application sometimes starts ok, but i've got an issue when AuditModule or LoadersModule can't be resolved because of "CommonModule" with exception descibed above.

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    private const string ModuleCatalogUri = "/ModerationSlUserInteface;component/ModulesCatalog.xaml";

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(StackPanelRegionAdapter).Assembly));
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var catalog = Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(new Uri(ModuleCatalogUri, UriKind.Relative));
        return catalog;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {

        //base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.RootVisual = (UIElement)this.Shell;
    }

    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        var stackPanelAdapterInstance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<StackPanelRegionAdapter>();
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(StackPanel), stackPanelAdapterInstance);
        return mappings;
    }
}
```

The code can be taken from [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8c3ZPcCrhUjMnBZclNIOEc4YUE)

P.S. In Shell.xaml.cs when I hit breakpoint on 
    if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == LoadersModuleName)

if the first Module is CommonModule then application starts ok. Else it falls with exception.

```
[Export]
public partial class Shell : UserControl, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    private const string LoadersModuleName = "LoadersModule";
    private static Uri LoadersViewUri = new Uri("/LoadersView", UriKind.Relative);

    public Shell()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
    public IModuleManager ModuleManager;

    [Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
    public IRegionManager RegionManager;

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        this.ModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == LoadersModuleName)
            {
                this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, LoadersViewUri);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found that you have to add any references in modules to the entry point project as well.

So if you reference `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions` in `AuditModule` (for example) then you need to add a reference to it into `MainProject` as well even though it's not directly referenced by any code in `MainProject`.

Comment: Thank you. I've made it working with referencing CommonModule in startup application. But how could it work before?